# Angular js bind local array with global scope

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, multidimensional-array, angularjs-bindings

I have an angular form. only 2 input box. I am taking the
values from input box and then saving them in an array.

then the problem begins. 
I want to  show the array wrapped with `<pre></pre>` tag
 how do I do that.  Code sample is like this.

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="qus" placeholder="Enter Question" ng-model="qus">
<input type="text" class="form-control" id="op1" placeholder="Option 1" ng-model="op1">
<label><input type="checkbox" ng-model="correct1">Correct</label>

<button class="form-control btn btn-primary" ng-click = "save()">Save</button>

<pre  ng-bind="dataShow"></pre>
```

Script:

```
var app = angular.module('qApp', []);
app.controller('qCtrl', function($scope) {
    var set = [];
    var op1 = [];
    $scope.save = function (){
        if($scope.correct1!==true){$scope.correct1=false;}      
        op1.push($scope.op1, $scope.correct1);
        var qus = [$scope.qus, op1];
        set.push(qus);
        console.log(qus);
        console.log(set);
        return set; 
    };
    $scope.dataShow = set.toString();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Move `$scope.dataShow = set.toString();` inside the function and remove the `return`:

```
$scope.save = function () {
    var set = [];
    var op1 = [];

    if ($scope.correct1 !== true) {
        $scope.correct1 = false;
    }

    op1.push($scope.op1, $scope.correct1);

    var qus = [$scope.qus, op1];
    set.push(qus);
    console.log(qus);
    console.log(set);
    $scope.dataShow = set.toString();
};
```

Comment: Thank you. now its showing as string. but i want to show as an array structure.

Comment: If you mean as a JSON representation of the array change `set.toString` to `JSON.stringify(set)`

Comment: After using JSON.stringify for the first entry the output looks like 
[["q1",
  ["o1",false]
]] 
and for the second entry output is 
[["q1",
   ["o1",false,"o2",true]],
["q2",
  ["o1",false,"o2",true]
]]

But I want like this 
[["q1",
   ["o1",false,]],
 ["q2",
   ["o2",true]
]]
How to do that???
true/false is the value of a chk box.